# Render custom field's value as rendered HTML not literal value

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I am trying to get HTML content to print in NetSuite's Advanced PDF/HTML Templates. Does anyone know if this is possible?

In this example, `custbody_print_content` is a custom field. Its value is:

```
<h1>Tiger</h1>
```

The template source code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">

<pdf>
  <body>
    ${record.custbody_print_content}
  </body>
</pdf>
```

I get this output:

```
<h1>Tiger</h1>
```

but I do not want the literal HTML. I want the interpreted HTML, like this:

## Tiger

---

---

I tried some of the built-ins that were mentioned in the comments, but I still do not get what I want.  The picture below shows the template and the printout.  The Zebra example has the desired result.

[image]

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like NetSuite escapes the html when it saves.  This means that when you type this in the form's text box:

```
<b>Marmot</b>
```

NetSuite "escapes" it and saves it like this:

```
&lt;b&gt;Marmot&lt;/b&gt;
```

So in the FreeMarker template, you need to unescape it.  I could not find any built-in feature to do this, but I can use `?replace`.  My current solution looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">

<pdf>
    <body>
        ${record.custbody_print_content?replace('<br />', '')?replace('&lt;', "\l")?replace('&gt;', "\g")}
    </body>
</pdf>
```

If anyone knows an easier way to do this, then let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the no_esc built-in. E.g

```
 ${record.custbody_print_content?no_esc}
```

Also I don't think this should make a difference but your xml is unusual in that it doesn't have a head element

Try getting rid of the extra space between the DOCTYPE and the `<pdf>` element and add this before the `<body>` opening tag

```
<head>
    <link name="verdana" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.verdana}" src-bold="${nsfont.verdana_bold}" bytes="2"></link>
</head>
```

Comment: Ahh, beat me to it...again! :)

Comment: Is there something else I am missing?  I keep getting an error when I save the template.  It does not seem to like the "?no_esc".

[Syntax error in template "template" in line 5, column 24:
?no_esc can't be used here, as the current output format isn't a markup (escaping) format: undefined(mimeType=null, class=f.c.UndefinedOutputFormat)]

Comment: Still not working.  "?html" converts the text to html entities.  Now the print shows: &lt;h1&gt;Tigers&lt;/h1&gt;

Comment: How do you know what the value of your custom record is? Have you tried retrieving it and printing it to the console? Or looking at it in xml view? (add `&xml=T` to the record's url)

Comment: The value seems OK.  XML is "<custbody_print_content><b>Tiger</b></custbody_print_content>".  In browser console, nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_print_content') is "<b>Tiger</b>".

Comment: How are you rendering it?

Comment: In the Estimate transaction, I click the print button, which then creates a PDF.  (Is that what you are asking for?)

Comment: Those did not work either, but thanks for the help and suggestions.  However, I did find a solution. (not the best, but it is better than nothing)